# React Native showing text twice in Apple, Once in Android

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I have a react native code, using expo, with a graph with text. In Apple, this application is showing it twice. In Android, once.

Here is the code:

```
import { ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text, View, Alert, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

...

// Charts
import * as scale from 'd3-scale'
import { ProgressCircle, LineChart, XAxis, Grid } from 'react-native-svg-charts';


.... <Other Code> ... 

        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
            <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>
<ProgressCircle
    style={{ height: 150, width: 150 }}
    startAngle={-Math.PI * 0.5}
    endAngle={Math.PI * 0.5}
    progress={this.state.perFirstTier}
    progressColor={constants.BGC_GREEN}
    strokeWidth={10}>
    {* THIS IS WHAT IS DOUBLED*}
    <Text key ='percentage' style={{
        position: "absolute",
        marginLeft: 65, marginTop: 50
    }}>{(this.state.perFirstTier * 100).toFixed(0)}%</Text>

</ProgressCircle>
<View style={{ marginTop: -40, flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
    <Text style={styles.description}>{i18n.t('activityDashboard.firstGoalDesc')}</Text>
    {/* Show colored badge if 100%*/}
    {this.state.perSecondTier == 1
        ? <Image style={styles.medalImage} source={require('../../utils/images/silver_medal.png')}></Image>
        : <Image style={styles.medalImage} source={require('../../utils/images/grey_medal.png')}></Image>
    }
</View>

        </View>
```

Here is an image comparison of Apple versus Android:

[image]

[image]

Why is this happening, and how can I make it only show once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because progress is already declared in the ProgressCircle component, and it's rendered inside it. Just remove the Text component from the ProgressCircle. I guess it has overflow hidden on Android so it's not displayed there.

Comment: I ended up removing it from inside the circle, and putting it below. I offset the text with a -100 marginTop until it sat on top of the circle.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue trying to render **YAxis** as **< Text >** on **iOS14**. I used **< Text >** because had a hard time using **YAxis** for putting the label at the top of the chart bar.

My specs:

```
{
    "expo": "~39.0.2",
    "react-native-svg-charts": "^5.4.0",
    "react-native-svg": "12.1.0"
}
```

Code:

```
const Values = ({ x, y, data }) => {
return (
    data.map((value, index) => {
        return (
            <Text
                key={index}
                style={{
                    color: '#6e6969',
                    fontSize: 10,
                    position: 'absolute',
                    left: x(index) + 1,
                    top: y(value) - 15
                }}
            >
                {value}
            </Text>
        )
    })
)}

<BarChart
    style={styles.chart}
    data={data.plot}
    spacing={0.2}
    svg={{ fill: 'rgba(134, 65, 244, 0.8)' }}
    contentInset={{ top: 20, bottom: 20, left: 0, right: 0 }}
>
    <Values />
</BarChart>

<XAxis
    style={{ marginHorizontal: -10 }}
    data={data.plot}
    formatLabel={(value, index) => data.labels[index]}
    contentInset={{ left: 30, right: 30 }}
    svg={{ fontSize: 10, fill: colors.medium }}
/>
```

Result

[image: on iOS]

What I needed to do was wrapper the **< Text >** into a **< View >** and the issue was solved:

Changed code:

```
const Values = ({ x, y, data }) => {
return (
    data.map((value, index) => {
        return (
            <View key={index}>
                <Text
                    style={{
                        color: '#6e6969',
                        fontSize: 10,
                        position: 'absolute',
                        left: x(index) + 1,
                        top: y(value) - 15
                    }}
                >
                {value}
            </Text>
        </View>
        )
    })
)}
```

Result

[image: On iOS]

Both codes worked fine on Android, though.

Comment: Yes, wrapping my text elements inside the View fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if all else fails, try adding a rendering condition for iOS platform.

```
<ProgressCircle
  style={{ height: 150, width: 150 }}
  startAngle={-Math.PI * 0.5}
  endAngle={Math.PI * 0.5}
  progress={this.state.perFirstTier}
  progressColor={constants.BGC_GREEN}
  strokeWidth={10}
>
  {/* THIS IS WHAT IS DOUBLED */}
  {Platform.OS === 'ios' 
    ? <View />
    : (
        <View>
          <Text
            key ='percentage'
            style={{
              position: "absolute",
              marginLeft: 65,
              marginTop: 50
            }}
          >
            {(this.state.perFirstTier * 100).toFixed(0)}%
          </Text>
        </View>
    )
  }
</ProgressCircle>
```